# Install Joomla on Windows Server

Tags: windows, joomla

I read many tutorials about how to install Joomla on Windows Server IIS (No WAMP, XAMPP), but i got confused. Can you please give me instructions how to do it properly, and what tools will i need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way that I found to get everything installed without a lengthy tutorial is to use Microsoft's WebMatrix.  It installs all of the prerequisites for you and if you need anything extra components for your projects (s) you can utilize the MS Web Platform afterwards.

[Microsoft WebMatrix for Joomla](http://www.microsoft.com/web/joomla)

All you need is a vanilla Windows load and the installer will manage the rest.